# Listening to recorded music after a nuclear war

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic

Here's one of those stories that I remember only a scene from, yet that may be enough to identify it. The story is set years after a nuclear apocalypse.

In the ruins, a few survivors gather to hear music on a record player (evidently a hand-cranked Victrola, though I don't recall that specifically).

The diamond needle has been replaced by a sharp thorn. They listen to a piece by Beethoven, and the man playing it sadly muses on how much longer people will be able to hear this music before the records and player wear out and it is lost to humanity.

I probably read this story in an English-language anthology published some time between 1945 and 1975.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This must be *[The Portable Phonograph](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?69738)*, a short story by Walter Van Tilburg Clark, first published in 1941 in *The Yale Review*.

The central character is an old man named Doctor Jenkins. He is a member of four survivors who meet once a week to discuss literature (such as Moby Dick, Shakespeare, and The Bible), and to play one of his dozen precious records. As the OP recalled, the stylus of the phonograph has had to be replaced with a thorn, although on special occasions Jenkins uses one of his diminishing stock of steel needles, and the records are almost worn out - he only dares to play them once a week.

Rather than Beethoven though, the old man plays a nocturne by Debussy, and the men surround the machine, almost worshiping it, as it plays the music. The next week he promises to play the "New York", and the men disperse. When he is alone Jenkins hides the phonograph, the records, and his books, clearly afraid someone will try to steal them.

A copy of the story can be read [here](https://www.scasd.org/cms/lib/PA01000006/Centricity/Domain/1487/Portable%20Phonograph.pdf) (although you will have to twist your neck).

Comment: How does a story written in 1941 refer to a nuclear war?  Is the 1941 date incorrect, or does the story just talk about a devastating conventional war as against nuclear war?

Comment: There is no mention of *nuclear* war, just mention of the craters left by "giant bombs", and the tank tracks still visible in the landscape.

Comment: @user23087 There used to be a genre called "science fiction" where they told stories of things that didn't exist yet in the real world. As a child I read "science fiction" stories about space voyages to other planets, when the highest altitude reached by a rocket in real life was 250 miles. So I can believe that they were writing "science fiction" stories about atomic war before the first atomic bomb had exploded..

Comment: @user14111 I stand corrected.  I had been under the impression that no one seriously thought of atomic weapons prior to 1940s.But after reading your comment I tried a book from 1931 (EE Smith's "Spacehounds of IPC").  And on page 20 it says "... Roeser and the IPC with their really effective atomic bombs, had a big part in the unification of the world into one nation so wars could no longer interfere with progress".

Comment: Wow, two correct answers, so quickly, and both good! Which to choose? I like the right-side-up text from Valorum's answer and the description from Clara Diaz Sanchez' answer. OK, Clara, this time you get the check mark! 
As to comments -- Well, I read it a long time ago, most likely in the 1968 edition of _Adventures in Tomorrow_, and you are right, there is no indication of nuclear war, though this story would not be the first to show the results of conventional warfare on an apocalyptic scale. It left an impression but I don't have an eidetic memory.

Comment: @user23087 "Spacehounds of IPC" was extensively revised for book publication in **1947**. In the original 1931 magazine serialization that sentence reads: "At about this same time Roeser and the Interplanetary Corporation had a big part in the unification of the world into one nation, so that wars could no longer interfere with progress." However, I'm pretty sure we can find some fictional atomic weapons before the 1940s.

Comment: @user23087 [Technovelgy](http://technovelgy.com/ct/content.asp?Bnum=1086) attributes the fictional invention of atomic bombs to H. G. Wells in 1914.

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron The story is also in Bradbury's *Timeless Stories* anthology, which is available to borrow from the Internet Archive: https://archive.org/details/timelessstoriesf00brad

Comment: @user14111 Olaf Stapledon's _Last and First Men_ (1930) comes to mind as an example. His atomic weapon is used incautiously near a source of the element that supplies the energy, and whole mountain ranges explode in a chain reaction.

Comment: @user14111 And Stephen Vincent Benet wrote a famous postapocalyptic story, "By the Waters of Babylon", in 1937. I think H. G. Wells did as well. Aerial bombardment in World War I, along with the use of poison gas, frightened people into thinking along these terms.

Comment: Luckily many PDF readers (including that built into Chrome!) can rotate the view, saving the strain on our necks

Comment: @user23087 See also [Which Sci-Fi work first showed Nuclear Weapons?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/162986/31394)

Comment: "although you will have to twist your neck" - or hit the "rotate" button in your PDF viewer. I know Chrome and Firefox's PDF viewers both have that functionality, and of course Adobe Acrobat has it.

Comment: @user14111: *The World Set Free* is a remarkable book, and I was astonished that Wells came up with the idea of an atomic bomb just from reading a seminal paper on the atomic decay of radium, but apart from the basic idea of making a bomb by controlling the rate of decay, his atomic bombs are quite different from real ones.

Comment: @Beta Wells's atomic bombs are different from real ones, and his spaceships are different from real ones, and Asimov's robots are different from real ones, and when there are real time machines I'm sure they will be quite different from any of the science-fictional time machines. I guess that's why the people who write that stuff are writers and not inventors.

Answer (score 19):

Could this be Walter Van Tilburg Clark's story “*The Portable Phonograph*”?

Three men visit a man in a cave who possesses the titular phonograph. He mentions that he has been using thorns as needles but for tonight's presentation he will use one of his rare steel needles

> The old man rose again in his difficult way, and went to the
> back of the cell. He returned and placed tenderly upon the packed
> floor, where the firelight might fall upon it, an old portable phonograph in a black case. He smoothed the top with his hand, and then opened it. The lovely green-felt-covered disk became
> visible.
>
> "I have been using thorns as needles," he said. "But tonight,
> because we have a musician among us" — he bent his head to the  young man, almost invisible in the shadow — "I will use a steel
> needle. There are only three left."

The story can be read in full [here](https://archive.org/stream/ideasincontext00sati/ideasincontext00sati_djvu.txt)