# WWII Naval short story

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, alternate-history

I am trying to locate a short story about a new radar being tested by the US Navy during WWII.  The captain of the test vessel encounters a Japanese fleet heading to the west coast and using the new radar was able to defeat the convoy.  I remember at the end the president, unprepared for the invasion, asked for the captain to surrender and the captain's reply was something like, who should I surrender to.

Comment: Welcome to the site Mark, thanks for your first post =) Would you happen to remember any other details: particularly external details such as how old you were when you read it, when it's likely to have been written, was it in a collection with other short stories, what language was it in - all that kind of stuff. Have a look at the list on [this page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) and see if you can tick off any items

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Short story...probably pre WW2. About a battleship ordered to surrender](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/70618/short-story-probably-pre-ww2-about-a-battleship-ordered-to-surrender)

Comment: @ZeissIkon Neither this question nor the target have accepted answers. You can post the answer from there here, if you like. Until then, we don't vote to close as duplicates, as per [this meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7065/70236).

Answer (score 4):

As noted in the answer to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/70618/short-story-probably-pre-ww2-about-a-battleship-ordered-to-surrender), this seems to be "Politics" by Murray Leinster.  The story points up how technology (the new radar, tied to gun training computers) can affect politics.  Originally published in *Amazing* in June, 1932 (available for free at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Amazing_Stories_v07n03_1932-06_cape1736#page/n77/mode/2up)), it was (as far as I can find) last printed in *18 Greatest Science Fiction Stories*, from Tempo, 1971.